# KnpSnappyBundle generates The exit status code '2'

Tags: symfony, pdf

I'm trying to generate an invoice pdf, so I'm using KnpSnappyBundle over symfony2 & twig to generate a pdf from html

On my ubuntu everything is working fine, in the production environment (FreeBSD, shared hosting) I get an error that I don't understand.
my config

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     "%kernel.root_dir%/../bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386"
        options:    
            lowquality: false
            encoding: UTF-8
    image:
        enabled:    false
        binary:     "%kernel.root_dir%/../bin/wkhtmltoimage-i386"
        options:    []
    temporary_folder: %kernel.cache_dir%/snappy
```

the error

```
[2016-02-07 01:07:05] snappy.DEBUG: Generate from HTML (<!DOCTYPE html> <html>     <head>         <meta charset="UTF-8" />         <title>MeVisa Invoice</ti) to file (/home/visallc/visallc.nichost.ru/src/MeVisa/ERPBundle/Controller/../../../../web/invoices/mevisa-invoice-3975-1.pdf). [] []
[2016-02-07 01:07:05] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "The exit status code '2' says something went wrong: stderr: "/home/visallc/visallc.nichost.ru/app/../bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected " stdout: "" command: /home/visallc/visallc.nichost.ru/app/../bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386 --encoding 'UTF-8' '/home/visallc/visallc.nichost.ru/app/cache/prod/snappy/knp_snappy56b66e89618f48.25746598.html' '/home/visallc/visallc.nichost.ru/src/MeVisa/ERPBundle/Controller/../../../../web/invoices/mevisa-invoice-3975-1.pdf'." at /home/visallc/visallc.nichost.ru/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php line 336 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): The exit status code '2' says something went wrong:\nstderr: \"/home/visallc/visallc.nichost.ru/app/../bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386: 1: Syntax error: \"(\" unexpected\n\"\nstdout: \"\"\ncommand: /home/visallc/visallc.nichost.ru/app/../bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386 --encoding 'UTF-8' '/home/visallc/visallc.nichost.ru/app/cache/prod/snappy/knp_snappy56b66e89618f48.25746598.html' '/home/visallc/visallc.nichost.ru/src/MeVisa/ERPBundle/Controller/../../../../web/invoices/mevisa-invoice-3975-1.pdf'. at /home/visallc/visallc.nichost.ru/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php:336)"} []
```

I've reduced the html to "Hello PDF" and I've tried different packages and different config. But they're all based on wkhtmltopdf.
Any help would be appreciated here, the point is to generate a PDF from html.
Thank you stackoverflowers

Comment: One solution would be an old php executable (prior v5.3) on the `$PATH` environment variable that's beeing used and causes these crashes.

Comment: @mblaettermann I don't understand the solution you propose, is there a link that describes this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upgrade your binary by downloading the latest version according to your platform.

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: Thank you @chalasr I checked it out, and it seems the only solution is to compile the source, which people are having issue with on BSD, I think I will search for another tool